# Angular Localisation: Typescript strings with $localise got translated but html with i18n didnt

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have created an Angular app and use $localize for typescripts string and i18n for html attributes. With ng extract-i18n I created the messages file and then translated to the target language. When I run the app only the $localize typescript are translated while the html ones are not.

Comment: what is your angular version? Can you show how you use i18n in html?